# asp.net mvc batch process (external thread) hangs, maybe timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis

Hello I have a Controller with a Json View like this:

```
    public JsonResult AjaxProcess()
    {
        //process id
        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
             doProcess(id);
        }
        return Json(id);
    }
```

The process works ok on my development machine with VisualStudio Web Express 2012 (with the built-in server), but in staging environment hangs during the processing, I'm thinking if it could be something about IIS (version 7) maybe a thread timeout? I understand that a new Thread() creates a thread outside the IIS Threading pool, so it is not affected to IIS thread timeout, Is it?

Comment: I don't see you using `Thread.Start`.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a fast example and I forget the thread start, but, the question is about diferences between Dev server and IIS using thread() because on IIS the process hangs.

Comment: If your real code uses `Start`, then please edit it to include `Start`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this works on your development machine, you haven't issued the `Thread` to start. You need to call `Thread.Start` for this to start processing:

```
public JsonResult AjaxProcess()
{
    //process id
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    new Thread(() =>
    {
         doProcess(id);
    }).Start();
    return Json(id);
}
```

Although this is possible, i would recommend against using the `Thread` class to queue work on ASP.NET (And in general). IIS might attempt to recycle your app, and as you don't register your work with the ThreadPool it wont be aware of you running this background worker which will cause your thread to terminate and not complete.

If you're running on .NET Framework 4.5.2, look into [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx). If not, checkout Stephan Cleary's implementation of [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks)

Comment: Sorry, as I commented above I wrote a fast example and I forget the thread start. On the other hand, I understand what you say about IIS recycling, I thought the standard thread is not reached by the recycling process. What I want to do is to execute from the web a server task, no need to be related with IIS, can be a external process too, but I prefer to use the same code for simplicity, what do you recomend? The task is executed once or twice a month, no need of performance.

Comment: If the job is done once or twice a month, i would definitely consider using something that is outside the scope of your MVC project. I might even consider using windows [*Task Scheduler*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) or some sort of Windows Service whos sole responsibility is doing that particular job.